# Estimate the gradient of a function on a complete manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

There is a function $f$ on the smooth, complete manifold with $f(x_{t})=f(x)+td(x,y)$, $t \in [0,1]$, where $x$ and $y$ are fixed points on the manifold, $d(x,y)$  is the geodesic distance, $x_{t} = {\rm{exp}}_{x}(t \log_{x}(y))$. My question is: whether ${\rm{grad}} \, f(x_{t}) = \frac{\log_{x_{t}}(y)}{d(x_{t},y)}$, Or whether we can get $|| {\rm{grad}} \, f(x_{t}) ||_{x_{t}}$  ?

Comment: I have difficulty understanding your question. If $x,y$ are fixed _first_, then your condition on $f(x_t)$ only constrains $f$ along the geodesic segment joining $x$ and $y$, and in particular cannot say anything about the gradient of $f$ (which depends on values of $f$ off of the curve). // If you meant that your equation holds for ALL pairs $(x,y)$, then I claim that by symmetry no such function is possible.

Comment: Or do you only want "grad" to refer to $d/dt$?

Comment: I've left out a condition here that $f$ is a lipschitz function with lipschtiz  constant is equal to 1